# Status 400 (Bad Request) or 413 (Payload Too Large) for file size uploads violation?

Tags: rest, http, file-upload

Reading the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) page, it seems that there is some overlap between the two. Which is the best practice when uploaded max file size is exceded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

413 is the answer.

**400 - Bad Request**
The request could not be understood by the server due to **malformed syntax**. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

**413 Request Entity Too Large / Payload Too Large**
The server is refusing to process a request because the request entity **is larger than** the server is willing or able to process. [...]

Sources:

[400 status spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)

[413 status spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.11)

Comment: This answer is correct, but I'd like to suggest you remove thet link on RFC 2616. It has been obsoleted entirely by RFCs 7230ff.